# Run yesod devel as a background process

Tags: nginx, yesod

I have successfully used `Nginx` to deploy a `Yesod` app in my own `Ubuntu` server. The way I do it, I simply run `yesod devel` and `Nginx` does a reverse proxy to the correct port -->    `localhost:3000`

However, there's one problem. How do you run `yesod devel` as a background process?

In [Deploying Your Yesod Webapp](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp), there's a section discussing server processes. It says to create an Upstart config file and start. After I created the Upstart config file, I executed the command `sudo start yesodAppName`.

The problem is that I'm unable to access my Yesod app. There's probably something I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully found the solution.

The Chapter `Server Process` in [Deploying Your Yesod Webapp](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp#deploying-your-webapp_server_process) describes how to run a Yesod App as a server process. It says to create the following Upstart config file in /etc/init/mySite

```
description "My awesome Yesod application"
start on runlevel [2345];
stop on runlevel [!2345];
respawn
chdir /home/michael/sites/mysite
exec /home/michael/sites/mysite/dist/build/mysite/mysite
```

The problem is that the last line is incomplete. Yesod offers you to run your webapp in Development, Testing, Staging or Production mode. Therefore, you need to specify it in the `exec` command.

Here is an example:

```
exec /home/michael/sites/mysite/dist/build/mysite/mysite Development
```

or

```
exec /home/michael/sites/mysite/dist/build/mysite/mysite MODE
```

where MODE = Development, Testing, Staging or Production .

Comment: You can even override default params with environment variables like "exec PORT=8080 APPROOT=http://myapp.example.com /home/michael/sites/mysite/dist/build/mysite/mysite MODE"